# Jquery Uncheck all checkboxes dynamically added after ajax request

Tags: jquery

I have one ajax call which append a html into page. in that html i have few check boxes which i want to uncheck but my jquery code not working. if i copy that html into page then my code is working but same code not working when ajax dynamically add html including check boxes into pages. so please tell me where i made the mistake.

**This is my html which is getting added by ajax into pages**

```
<div class="single-slot">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input class="chkbox" checked name="2|Net Sales" type="checkbox" value="chart2_1" /><label>Net Sales</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class="chkbox" checked name="2|Revenue Growth- Reported" type="checkbox" value="chart2_2" /><label>Revenue Growth- Reported</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class="chkbox" checked name="2|Cost of Sales-GAAP" type="checkbox" value="chart2_3" /><label>Cost of Sales-GAAP</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".chkbox").each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `doc.ready` runs when the doc is ready, it's not `ajax.ready` - ie runs before your ajax.  Add the same code to your `$.ajax().done(()=>)` callback (or put in a function of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After DOMElements are rewritten by jQuery, you need to rebind events.

So you need to call the function not only from `document.ready` event but after ajax success.

For example:

```js
const ajaxLoad = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $("#root").html(`
  <div class="single-slot">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input class="chkbox" checked name="2|Net Sales" type="checkbox" value="chart2_1" /><label>Net Sales</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class="chkbox" checked name="2|Revenue Growth- Reported" type="checkbox" value="chart2_2" /><label>Revenue Growth- Reported</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class="chkbox" checked name="2|Cost of Sales-GAAP" type="checkbox" value="chart2_3" /><label>Cost of Sales-GAAP</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  `);
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
};

const uncheckAll = () => {
  $(".chkbox").each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  ajaxLoad().then(() => {
    uncheckAll();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div class="single-slot">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input class="chkbox" checked name="2|Net Sales" type="checkbox" value="chart2_1" /><label>Net Sales</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input class="chkbox" checked name="2|Revenue Growth- Reported" type="checkbox" value="chart2_2" /><label>Revenue Growth- Reported</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input class="chkbox" checked name="2|Cost of Sales-GAAP" type="checkbox" value="chart2_3" /><label>Cost of Sales-GAAP</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what resolve(); function does ? this also not very clear to me `return new Promise((resolve) => {`

Comment: I was trying to make a API mockup. Just ignore it.